# Select with except in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

General except query is like this

```
(SELECT * FROM name_of_table_one
 EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM name_of_table_two);
```

is there a way to write a query where I pass a list of values and perform except or intersect operation with a specific column of a table and select from that the list I had passed to DB.

Comment: Can you explain a bit how would be the table query? And the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a VALUES list.

```
select * from (values (1),(2),(100000001)) as f (aid)
    except 
select aid from pgbench_accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with the `IN` clause

"except":

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column NOT IN (list of values)
```

"intersect":

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column IN (list of values)
```